# Функция Sleep() в PHP

Tags: php

Есть файл index.php и progress.php

В файле index.php находится:

```
<?php
sleep(5);
echo 1;
?>
```

В файле progress.php находится:

```
<?php
echo 'test';
?>
```

Почему при открытии http://site.ru/index.php замедляется и http://site.ru/progress.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что, у вас один php.exe процесс на сервере запущен.

Comment: @manking, это как-то исправимо?

Comment: Смысл этого в следующем. (При определенной настройке)
Когда ваши файлы .php компилируются, то на сервере запускается процесс php.exe. 

Если к сайту осуществляется множество запросов, то дополнительно могут запускаться еще процессы. 

Это может помочь в случаи если сервер имеет например многоядерный процессор(1 процесс не может использовать больше 1 ядра).

Вам может помочь только если как то привязать index.php к определенному процессу, а progress.php к другому.

Но я знаю как это сделать, только на IIS под windows, при запуске через протокол fastcgi.

А у вас наверняка веб сервер apache.

Comment: @manking, так не пойдёт. Уж слишком геморно.

Просто пишу прогресс бар. Т.е, если страница загрузилась, то он заполняется на 100%. Со страницы index.php выполняется ajax GET запрос например на страницу test.php и если она прогрузилась, то прогресс бар заполняется на 100%. А сам PHP код прогресс бара, который во время прогрузки увеличивает на 2% на странице progress.php. Но тогда получается, что для теста, если на страницу test.php поставить sleep(5), то сразу все другие страницы также начинают грузиться через 5 сек и соответственно progress.php уже ничего не значит. Может можно как-то легче?

Comment: Не очень понятно. 
Вы когда заходите на сайт то идете на index.php?

Страница test.php для чего нужна? 

Вам полоска загрузки что должна показать, статус работы самой страницы test.php или что то где то куда то загружается?

Comment: @manking. На index.php видна сама полоса загрузки http://u.to/Qd5ZAg . При нажатии на ссылку q, выполняется loader(0); $.get('test.php', function(e) {if(e) loader(100)});. Функция loader() имеет ajax запрос на страницу progress.php. И с каждым коннектом туда увеличивает счётчик на +2(сессии). Т.е на 2%. Так вот, если в test.php прописать sleep(5), чтобы понаблюдать за медленным заполнение прогресс-бара, то и progress.php начинает срабатывать только через 5 секунд, соответственно полоса не заполняется во время прогрузки, а заполняется сразу на 100% тогда, когда уже всё в test.php прогрузилось.

Comment: Медленное исполнения чего? движения полоски от 0 до 2%?

То есть у вас например 50 ajax запросов каждый двигает полоску на 2%. И вам хочется посмотреть на медленное выполнение всего процесса?
Если да, то это надо делать через javascript, ставить таймеры.

Comment: @manking, Хм, действительно. О javascript не подумал. Хотя с ним даже проще. Спасибо, как всегда даёте полезные советы!